# How to connect two mongo database in spring boot without using MongoRepository

Tags: mongodb, spring-boot, spring-boot-maven-plugin

Hi I have to connect two different mongoDB database in spring boot .

I mentioned in application properties file as :

```
primary.mongodb.database=mydb
primary.mongodb.port=*****
primary.mongodb.host=******


secondary.mongodb.database=mydb2
secondary.mongodb.port=******
secondary.mongodb.host=******
```

I have created two configuration file with common abstarct class :

```
package webservice.com.employee.configure;

import com.mongodb.MongoClient;
import org.springframework.data.mongodb.MongoDbFactory;
import org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate;
import org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.SimpleMongoDbFactory;

public abstract class AbstractMongoConfig {
    //Mongo DB Properties

private String host , database;
private int port;

//Setter methods go here..

/*
 * Method that creates MongoDbFactoray
 * Common to both of the MongoDb connections
 */
//org.springframework.data.mongodb.MongoDatabaseFactory
public MongoDbFactory mongoDbFactory() throws Exception {
    return new SimpleMongoDbFactory(new MongoClient(host, port), database);
}

/*
 * Factory method to create the MongoTemplate
 */
abstract public MongoTemplate getMongoTemplate() throws Exception;

package webservice.com.employee.configure;

import org.springframework.boot.context.properties.ConfigurationProperties;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Primary;
import org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate;

@Configuration //Configuration class
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "primary.mongodb") //Defines my custom prefix and points to the primary db properties
public class CommonMongoConfig extends AbstractMongoConfig {
    /**
     * Implementation of the MongoTemplate factory method
     * @Bean gives a name (primaryMongoTemplate) to the created MongoTemplate instance
     * @Primary declares that if MongoTemplate is autowired without providing a specific name,
     * this is the instance which will be mapped by default
     */
    @Primary
    @Override
    public @Bean(name = "primaryMongoTemplate") MongoTemplate getMongoTemplate() throws Exception {
        return new MongoTemplate(mongoDbFactory());
    }
}

package webservice.com.employee.configure;

import org.springframework.boot.context.properties.ConfigurationProperties;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate;

@Configuration //Configuration
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "secondary.mongodb") //Defines my custom prefix and points to the secondary db properties
public class SecondaryMongoConfig extends AbstractMongoConfig {
    /**
     * Implementation of the MongoTemplate factory method
     * @Bean gives a name (primaryMongoTemplate) to the created MongoTemplate instance
     * Note that this method doesn't have @Primary
     */
    @Override public @Bean(name = "secondaryMongoTemplate")
    MongoTemplate getMongoTemplate() throws Exception {
        return new MongoTemplate(mongoDbFactory());
    }
}
```

But I am not getting why I am getting below error ..

```
 /\\ / ___'_ __ _ _(_)_ __  __ _ \ \ \ \
( ( )\___ | '_ | '_| | '_ \/ _` | \ \ \ \
 \\/  ___)| |_)| | | | | || (_| |  ) ) ) )
  '  |____| .__|_| |_|_| |_\__, | / / / /
 =========|_|==============|___/=/_/_/_/
 :: Spring Boot ::        (v2.3.0.RELEASE)

2020-05-26 17:04:53.191  INFO 4940 --- [           main] w.com.employee.EmployeeApplication       : Starting EmployeeApplication on SWATI with PID 4940 (C:\Users\swatiswagatika\Desktop\Study\fullstack\project-1\employee\target\classes started by swatiswagatika in C:\Users\swatiswagatika\Desktop\Study\fullstack\project-1\employee)
2020-05-26 17:04:53.191  INFO 4940 --- [           main] w.com.employee.EmployeeApplication       : No active profile set, falling back to default profiles: default
2020-05-26 17:04:54.063 ERROR 4940 --- [           main] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application run failed

java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not find class [org.springframework.data.mongodb.MongoDatabaseFactory]
    at org.springframework.util.ClassUtils.resolveClassName(ClassUtils.java:335) ~[spring-
```

I tried everywhere to fix this issue ..
Any help will be appreciated

dependency :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.0.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>webservice.com</groupId>
    <artifactId>employee</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>employee</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-mongodb</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-data-mongodb</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.0.RELEASE</version>
            <!--<version>2.2.4.RELEASE</version>-->
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
            <version>5.2.6.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.junit.vintage</groupId>
                    <artifactId>junit-vintage-engine</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>de.flapdoodle.embed</groupId>
            <artifactId>de.flapdoodle.embed.mongo</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mongodb</groupId>
            <artifactId>mongodb-driver</artifactId>
            <version>3.11.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-data-mongodb</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.1.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

Comment: Did you add MongoDB's dependency in pom.xml?

Comment: yes .. I have added dependency ..